# tlmgr and texdoc. What do I get?

Tags: tlmgr, texdoc

I have just called `\tlmgr update -all` and got about 140+ updates, one of which was for `bookman`. After the update finished I did `texdoc bookman` as I did not know/remember what that was. In return I got `psnfss2e.pdf` about using PostScript Fonts with LaTeX.

How do I find out what `bookman` is all about?

Answer (score 1):

The Package Overview for psnfss2e says that the bookman package loads the Bookman font for the roman family, the Avant Garde font for the sans serif family, the Courier font fro the typewriter family, and leaves the math formula font as the default (approximately(?) CM Roman).